# How is this transformation measure preserving? Example from Birkhoff, George David (1942), "What is the ergodic theorem?"

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ergodicity

I'm reading Birkhoff, George David (1942), "What is the ergodic theorem?", doi:10.2307/2303229, and I'm stuck on his 2nd example:

> the line segment is divided into the infinite set of intervals, [0,1/2), [1/2,3/4], (3/4,7/8]..., and then the second interval is interchanged with the first, the fourth with the third, etc., thus defining the transformation T.

But surely the measure of the 1st interval is 0.5, the second 0.25, so the measure is not preserved. Surely I'm missing something...

Comment: Birkhoff is speaking about the transformation of the whole interval $0 \leq x <1$. The *sum* of the measures of all the intervals is preserved.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thank you. How about making that an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. I hope that it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Birkhoff is speaking about the transformation of the whole interval $0\leq x < 1$. The sum of the measures of all the intervals is preserved.

That transformation $T$ can be written in the following way. Let $I_n$ ($n=1,2, \dots$) be the $n-$th interval of the partition proposed by Birkhoff. $T$ maps
$$
\begin{align}
I_2 &\rightarrow I_1\\
I_1 &\rightarrow I_2\\
I_2 &\rightarrow I_1\\
I_1 &\rightarrow I_2\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
All the intervals on the left and on the right of each arrow being the intervals before and after the trandformation.

Comment: Thank you again.